# How to model this constraint?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, combinatorial-optimization

I have a system with $C$ machine and $U$ users.
The decision variables are $d_{u,c}$ and ${\bf f}_{u,c}$ with $c=1,2,\cdots,C$ and $u=1,2,\cdots,U$, where

$$d_{u,c}\in\{0,1\}$$
$${\bf f}_{u,c}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}\hspace{3mm}\text{(a vector of }N\text{ complex elements)}$$

I want to put a constraint like this:

If $d_{u,c}=0$, then $||{\bf f}_{u,c}||^2=0$

If $d_{u,c}=1$, then $0<||{\bf f}_{u,c}||^2\le T$

Here, $||\cdot||$ is Euclidean norm and $T>0$

How to model this constraints mathematically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$d_{u,c}\sigma  \le ||{\bf f}_{u,c}||^2\le Td_{u,c}$
where $\sigma$ is a very small number based on scale of $f$

Comment: Yes, correct now.